# Visual Studio auto tab "Move Lines Up/Down"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2019, visual-assist

I normally select a portion of code and then use Alt+Up/Down to perform a "Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp" or "Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown". Trying to fix another auto formatting issue, I changed a substantial amount of settings. Then I didn't remember which ones I changed, So I decided to reset everything by "Tools-> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all".

Now when I perform this Move Up and Down, the code is not auto idented, so I need to manually tab it or do an auto format.

I tried reinstalling and installing everything, but for some reason Visual Studio remembers keeps doing it by default.

I don't know if this is the default behaviour or is it something I configured and I lost it by performing a reset.

Can anyone help me with this?

I use the C++ Editor and I have Visual Assist installed.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean “the code is not auto idented”? You mean Alt+Up/Down will auto format the codes?

Comment: Either I'm going crazy or it used to be like that. I even remember that it was funny to see how the source was wobbling while I was moving a section from one method to another.
Anyway, I think I got used to not having it.

Comment: I don't think that Alt+Up/Down will auto format the codes, of course, you can try to report this to [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem) to confirm this if you want. Anyway, I'm willing to help if you meet other similar issues : D

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It wasn't auto formatted but "auto tabbed/indented" if that make sense. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl+K and ctrl+F selecting all(ctrl+A)

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it used to do it automatically while I was moving the selected source up and down. Thanks for your answer.